# $1 \times 3$ tangent plane vs. gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Say we have some function $f(x,y,z)=xyz$ or whatever. It goes from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}$. If we want the tangent plane of the function, we need to differentiate it, and this gives us a $1 \times 3$ matrix, but this special derivative is also known as the gradient. However, the gradient is the vector that is orthogonal to the tangent plane. How can these 2 be both parallel and orthogonal simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plane is defined by a vector and a point: the point is some point that is in the plane, and the vector is orthogonal to every line in the plane.  As you say, you can find the tangent plane with the gradient.  The gradient is *normal* to the surface, the plane it defines is parallel to the surface.

Comment: In my example, the tangent plane is equal to the gradient, but you say that the gradient is normal to the surface and the plane is parallel to the surface. If the gradient = plane, how can one be normal to the surface and also be parallel to the surface?

Comment: Gradient != plane.  The gradient is orthogonal to every line in the plane.  The gradient is a vector that defines the plane, but it is not the plane.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Surface_normal_illustration.png

Comment: But in order to obtain the tangent plane, you need to differentiate the function. If you differentiate the function in my example, you get exactly the gradient, so it seems the tangent plane and gradient are equal?

Comment: If you differentiate a function of one variable, do you get a tangent line?  You get the *slope* of the tangent line, which is essentially it's direction.  The tangent line is found with the slope and a point on the curve.  Similarly, the gradient gives the direction of the tangent plane; this combined with a point on the surface defines the tangent plane.

Comment: I don't understand how if the tangent plane is parallel to the surface, and the gradient is normal to the surface, how can the gradient give the direction of the tangent plane if it's normal to it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13712/discussion-between-jpkotta-and-user130018)